# Linux EC2 ping will not reply

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

Really struggling to pin point a network gateway issue in EC2.

I've set a new machine. Exact same Security groups, subnet and VPC setup as previous one and am trying to ping  third machine..

Tcp dump from the 3rd server shows similar response from these two machines I am comparing:

```
$> tcpdump -qtln icmp
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
IP NEW_MACHINE > THIRD_MACHNE: ICMP echo request, id 2750, seq 1, length 64
IP THIRD_MACHNE > NEW_MACHINE: ICMP echo reply, id 2750, seq 1, length 64
IP OLD_MACHINE > NEW_MACHINE: ICMP echo request, id 63237, seq 1, length 64
IP NEW_MACHINE > OLD_MACHINE: ICMP echo reply, id 63237, seq 1, length 64
```

iptables are empty (iptables -L).

When I ping from `old` machine, I get back a response and all is well, from the new machine, 100% packet loss:

```
[root@ansible-1-1b network-scripts]#  ping -v THIRD_MACHINE
PING THIRD_MACHINE (THIRD_MACHINE) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- THIRD_MACHINE ping statistics ---
16 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 15365ms
```

These are EC2 machines, in same VPC and as far as I can tell Ec2 config is similar (same vpc, same security groups, no specific rules for either machines) Any ideas where I should next be looking at?

The one major diff I see is the working machine:

```
uname -r
2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64
```

vs the failing one:

```
uname -r
4.9.43-17.39.amzn1.x86_64
```

Security Groups from AWS, for the two pinging machines:
[Client security group](https://github.com/AvnerCohen/AvnerCv/blob/master/images/skitch_client_sg.png)

On the target machine:
[Server sg setup](https://github.com/AvnerCohen/AvnerCv/blob/master/images/skitch_server_sg.png)

Maybe a new flag I am missing?

For what it's worth I use ping for the test, but SSH is timing out just as well.

Comment: Can you post the security group configuration?

Comment: Sure.. (Upload to serverfault does not seem to work, added direct github links... :()

Comment: Is that port -1 correct?

Comment: You allow ICMP from all address (0.0.0.0/0) on the working machine, but only from 10.2/16 and 10.20/16 on the server. Can you try opening up ICMP from all and retrying?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly basic, but needed some time and help to figure this out.. The problem was in the AWS routing table setup of the third machine.
It had a specific rule to allow one machine in, but not the other...